# Getting headers already sent when in destructor

Tags: php, class

I'm getting this warning:

> Warning: session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent

But before it, I call `ob_start`.

**Test script:**

```
ob_start();
$session = new SessionClass();

echo "Test";
```

**SessionClass:**

```
function __destruct() {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    session_write_close();
}
```

Why am I seeing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See PHP docs for `__destruct()`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Destructors called during the script shutdown have HTTP headers
>   already sent.

`session_regenerate_id()` tries to send a cookie with the session id, but since you're calling it in a destructor the headers are already send - hence the error message.

Why do you need to regenerate the session id? Your code suggests that first you start a session, generate an id, send some data and then regenerate the session id before closing it. Unless you have a specific reason for this, you don't need to do that at all.